# Magento Error When Installing On Localhost Site

Tags: magento

So, I was normally installing Magento on my "localhost" 192.168.1.230 server. 
So I was happily installing Magento once I got to the "CONFIG" Step.

Here is my error:

```
Path "/var/www/html/magento/app/etc" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/magento_sample_data_for_1.1.2.sql" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/category" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/category/apparel.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/category/bedroom.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/category/camera.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/category/furniture.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/category/shirts.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/category/shoes.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/2" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/2/2" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/2/2/22-syncmaster-lcd-monitor.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/2/4" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/2/4/24-widescreen-flat-panel-lcd-monitor.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/1" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/1/9" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/1/9/19-widescreen-flat-panel-lcd-monitor.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/3" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/3/0" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/3/0/30-flat-panel-tft-lcd-cinema-hd-monitor.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/a" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/a/c" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/a/c/acer-ferrari-3200-notebook-computer-pc.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/a/k" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/a/k/akio-dresser.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/a/m" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/a/m/amd-a64-x2-3800-2-0ghz-oem.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/a/m/amd-phenom-x4-9850-black-ed-2-50ghz-retail.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/a/n" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/a/n/anashria-womens-premier-leather-sandal-2.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/a/n/anashria-womens-premier-leather-sandal-1.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/a/n/anashria-womens-premier-leather-sandal.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/a/p" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/a/p/apevia-black-x-cruiser-case-atx-mid-tower-case-default.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/a/p/apple-macbook-pro-ma464ll-a-15-4-notebook-pc.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/a/r" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/a/r/argus-qc-2185-quick-click-5mp-digital-camera-1.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/a/r/argus-qc-2185-quick-click-5mp-digital-camera-2.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/a/r/argus-qc-2185-quick-click-5mp-digital-camera-3.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/a/r/argus-qc-2185-quick-click-5mp-digital-camera-4.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/a/r/argus-qc-2185-quick-click-5mp-digital-camera.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/a/s" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/a/s/asics-men-s-gel-kayano-xii-1.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/a/s/asics-men-s-gel-kayano-xii-2.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/a/s/asics-men-s-gel-kayano-xii.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/a/t" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/a/t/at-t-8525-pda-1.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/a/t/at-t-8525-pda-2.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/a/t/at-t-8525-pda-3.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/a/t/at-t-8525-pda.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/b" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/b/a" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/b/a/barcelona-bamboo-platform-bed.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/b/l" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/b/l/blackberry-8100-pearl-1.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/b/l/blackberry-8100-pearl-2.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/b/l/blackberry-8100-pearl-3.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/b/l/blackberry-8100-pearl-4.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/b/l/blackberry-8100-pearl.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/c" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/c/a" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/c/a/canon-digital-rebel-xt-8mp-digital-slr-camera-1.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/c/a/canon-digital-rebel-xt-8mp-digital-slr-camera.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/c/a/canon-powershot-a630-8mp-digital-camera-with-4x-optical-zoom-1.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/c/a/canon-powershot-a630-8mp-digital-camera-with-4x-optical-zoom-2.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/c/a/canon-powershot-a630-8mp-digital-camera-with-4x-optical-zoom-3.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/c/a/canon-powershot-a630-8mp-digital-camera-with-4x-optical-zoom-4.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/c/a/canon-powershot-a630-8mp-digital-camera-with-4x-optical-zoom.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/c/h" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/c/h/chair-1.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/c/h/chair-2.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/c/h/chair.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/c/n" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/c/n/cn-clogs-beach-garden-clog-1.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/c/n/cn-clogs-beach-garden-clog-2.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/c/n/cn-clogs-beach-garden-clog-3.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/c/n/cn-clogs-beach-garden-clog-4.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/c/n/cn-clogs-beach-garden-clog.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/c/o" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/c/o/coalesce-functioning-on-impatience-t-shirt-1.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/c/o/coalesce-functioning-on-impatience-t-shirt.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/c/o/computer.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/c/o/couch-1.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/c/o/couch-2.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/c/o/couch.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/c/r" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/c/r/crucial-1gb-pc4200-ddr2-533mhz-memory.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/c/r/crucial-2gb-pc4200-ddr2-533mhz-memory.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/c/r/crucial-512mb-pc4200-ddr2-533mhz-memory.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/e" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/e/c" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/e/c/ecco-womens-golf-flexor-golf-shoe-1.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/e/c/ecco-womens-golf-flexor-golf-shoe-2.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/e/c/ecco-womens-golf-flexor-golf-shoe-3.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/e/c/ecco-womens-golf-flexor-golf-shoe-4.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/e/c/ecco-womens-golf-flexor-golf-shoe.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/g" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/g/a" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/g/a/gaming-computer.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/h" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/h/t" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/h/t/htc-touch-diamond.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/i" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/i/n" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/i/n/ink-eater-krylon-bombear-destroyed-tee-1.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/i/n/ink-eater-krylon-bombear-destroyed-tee-2.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/i/n/ink-eater-krylon-bombear-destroyed-tee.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/i/n/intel-c2d-e8400-3-0ghz-retail.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/i/n/intel-core-2-extreme-qx9775-3-20ghz-retail.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/k" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/k/e" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/k/e/kenneth-cole-new-york-men-s-con-verge-slip-on-1.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/k/e/kenneth-cole-new-york-men-s-con-verge-slip-on-2.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/k/e/kenneth-cole-new-york-men-s-con-verge-slip-on-3.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/k/e/kenneth-cole-new-york-men-s-con-verge-slip-on-4.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/k/e/kenneth-cole-new-york-men-s-con-verge-slip-on.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/k/o" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/k/o/kodak-easyshare-c530-5mp-digital-camera-1.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/k/o/kodak-easyshare-c530-5mp-digital-camera-2.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/k/o/kodak-easyshare-c530-5mp-digital-camera-3.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/k/o/kodak-easyshare-c530-5mp-digital-camera-4.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/k/o/kodak-easyshare-c530-5mp-digital-camera.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/l" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/l/o" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/l/o/logitech-cordless-optical-trackman.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/l/o/logitech-dinovo-edge-keyboard.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/m" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/m/a" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/m/a/magento-red-furniture-set-1.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/m/a/magento-red-furniture-set-2.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/m/a/magento-red-furniture-set.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/m/i" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/m/i/microsoft-natural-ergonomic-keyboard-4000.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/m/i/microsoft-wireless-optical-mouse-5000.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/m/y" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/m/y/my-computer.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/n" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/n/i" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/n/i/nine-west-women-s-lucero-pump-1.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/n/i/nine-west-women-s-lucero-pump-2.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/n/i/nine-west-women-s-lucero-pump.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/n/o" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/n/o/nokia-2610-phone-2.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/n/o/nokia-2610-phone-1.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/n/o/nokia-2610-phone-3.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/n/o/nokia-2610-phone-4.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/n/o/nokia-2610-phone.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/n/z" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/n/z/nzxt-lexa-silver-aluminum-atx-mid-tower-case-default.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/o" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/o/l" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/o/l/olympus-stylus-750-7-1mp-digital-camera-1.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/o/l/olympus-stylus-750-7-1mp-digital-camera-2.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/o/l/olympus-stylus-750-7-1mp-digital-camera-3.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/o/l/olympus-stylus-750-7-1mp-digital-camera-4.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/o/l/olympus-stylus-750-7-1mp-digital-camera.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/o/t" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/o/t/ottoman-1.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/o/t/ottoman-2.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/o/t/ottoman.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/s" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/s/a" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/s/a/samsung-mm-a900m-ace-1.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/s/a/samsung-mm-a900m-ace-2.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/s/a/samsung-mm-a900m-ace.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/s/e" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/s/e/seagate-250gb-hd-5400rpm.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/s/e/seagate-500gb-hd-5400rpm.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/s/l" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/s/l/slr-camera-tripod-1.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/s/l/slr-camera-tripod-2.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/s/l/slr-camera-tripod.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/s/o" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/s/o/sony-ericsson-w810i-1.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/s/o/sony-ericsson-w810i-2.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/s/o/sony-ericsson-w810i-3.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/s/o/sony-ericsson-w810i-4.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/s/o/sony-ericsson-w810i.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/s/o/sony-vaio-11-1-notebook-pc.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/s/o/sony-vaio-vgn-txn27n-b-11-1-notebook-pc.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/s/t" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/s/t/steven-by-steve-madden-pryme-pump-1.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/s/t/steven-by-steve-madden-pryme-pump-2.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/s/t/steven-by-steve-madden-pryme-pump-3.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/s/t/steven-by-steve-madden-pryme-pump-4.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/s/t/steven-by-steve-madden-pryme-pump.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/t" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/t/e" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/t/e/test-phone-1.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/t/e/test-phone-2.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/t/e/test-phone-3.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/t/e/test-phone.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/t/h" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/t/h/the-get-up-kids-band-camp-pullover-hoodie-1.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/t/h/the-get-up-kids-band-camp-pullover-hoodie.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/t/h/the-only-children-paisley-t-shirt-1.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/t/h/the-only-children-paisley-t-shirt-2.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/t/h/the-only-children-paisley-t-shirt-3.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/t/h/the-only-children-paisley-t-shirt.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/t/o" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/t/o/toshiba-m285-e-14-1.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/t/o/toshiba-m285-e-14-2.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/t/o/toshiba-m285-e-14.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/u" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/u/n" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/u/n/universal-camera-case-1.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/u/n/universal-camera-case-2.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/u/n/universal-camera-case.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/u/n/universal-camera-charger.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/w" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/w/e" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/w/e/western-digital-500gb-hd-7200rpm.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/w/e/western-digital-1tb-hd-7200rpm.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/z" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/z/o" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/z/o/zolof-the-rock-and-roll-destroyer-lol-cat-t-shirt-2.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/z/o/zolof-the-rock-and-roll-destroyer-lol-cat-t-shirt-1.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/z/o/zolof-the-rock-and-roll-destroyer-lol-cat-t-shirt-3.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/catalog/product/z/o/zolof-the-rock-and-roll-destroyer-lol-cat-t-shirt.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/customer" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/dhl" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/dhl/logo.jpg" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/downloadable" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/xmlconnect" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/xmlconnect/custom" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/xmlconnect/custom/ok.gif" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/xmlconnect/original" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/xmlconnect/original/ok.gif" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/xmlconnect/system" must be writable.
Path "/var/www/html/magento/media/xmlconnect/system/ok.gif" must be writable.
```

Could You Guys Please Help Me? You aced my question last time within two answers!

Answer (score 1):

For the solution of this issue is :

You need to give permission to the root folder.
For Folder you need to give 755 permission
For Files you need to give 644 permission.

Use below command for permission to folder and files

Go to out side your Magento root Directory :

Command for 777 : sudo chmod -R 777 magentoRoot/*

Command for 755 : find magentoRoot/ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} +

Command for 644 : find magentoRoot/ -type f -exec chmod 644 {} +